# ConcurrentModificationException even with the use of Iterator in android ArrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I got a ConcurrentModificationExeption in what I thought to be a single thread case. I also know that if you iterate through a List and try to modify it in the loop, you would have an exception. Hence I actually iterate and modify it using an iterator. However, I still have the exception.

Basically, I am implementing some animation manager, and I store all my IAnimation objects in an ArrayList. There is one public method that changes the list, which is addAnimation. THere is another method that loops through the list, which is calculateTick. Since both methods are synchronized, I dont think I have a threading problem. And as mentioned earlier, I iterate thruogh the loop using the iterator. Do you guys have any ideas why I have this exception?

Here is my code:

```
    private List<IAnimation> animations = new ArrayList<IAnimation>();
    public synchronized void addAnimation(IAnimation animation) {
    animations.add(animation);
    mLooper.update();
    inAnimation = true;
}

public synchronized void calculateTick(float tpf) {     
    for (Iterator<IAnimation> iterator = animations.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        IAnimation animation= iterator.next();
                    boolean animateMore = animation.calculateTick(tpf);
        if (!animateMore ) {{
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

And here is my exception:

```
 E/AndroidHarness(9546): Exception thrown in Thread[GLThread 1260,5,main]
```

04-17 11:55:38.001: E/AndroidHarness(9546): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-17 11:55:38.001: E/AndroidHarness(9546):     at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.remove(ArrayList.java:582)
04-17 11:55:38.001: E/AndroidHarness(9546):     at com.avaya.mco.gui.animation.AnimationManager.calculateTick(AnimationManager.java:50)
04-17 11:55:38.001: E/AndroidHarness(9546):     at com.avaya.mco.gui.jmonkey.android.MyApplication.simpleUpdate(MyApplication.java:60)
04-17 11:55:38.001: E/AndroidHarness(9546):     at ......

Comment: Right now I have to iterate through a copy of the list and then remove from the original. But I think ArrayListIterator supposed to work in this case. Wonder if that is an android bug?

Comment: Something else is reading or modifying the list -- scour your code for anything else that would be doing so. This is far, far more likely than a bug in the implementation.

Comment: You are right. inside that loop there is a place that eventually results in a possible change in the list. Sadly I already knew it is more likely that my code is buggy, but having somebody else saying it again still help it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure there is no other function missing here that iterates over the list ? maybe something that plays the animation?

also, if that doesn't help , try using "ConcurrentLinkedQueue" :
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html
it's available to all versions , and it says that for the iterator :
"...The returned iterator is a "weakly consistent" iterator that will never throw ConcurrentModificationException, and guarantees to traverse elements as they existed upon construction of the iterator, and may (but is not guaranteed to) reflect any modifications subsequent to construction."

Comment: Thanks. There is no missing function there that iterates over the list. That loop is the loop that plays the animation. However in the code of one of the animations there is a place where I added more animations into the list. So the situation is that inside that loop itself, there is a point where an animation is added to the list, and then iterator.remove() is called, resulting in the exception. Using ConcurrentLinkedQueue should actually helped solving the exception also.

Comment: so it was another thread that was adding something to the collection , right?

Comment: No, it was the same thread actually. It happen in the same loop. The problem for me was that it was very deep down in the calling tree in some unexpected place that at first I did not see it at all.

Comment: well if the same thread is changing the collection , it can't cause any concurrency exception .

Comment: Indeed it can. For example, if you loop through an ArrayList using Iterator, or use the for each loop, and then inside the loop you add or remove elements then you might receive a ConcurrentModificationException on iterator.next() or iterator.hasNext() - the javadoc of the Iterator pretty much said so, for the case of fail-fast iterator (which applies for ArrayList). I just never thought that iterator.remove() would throw that exception.

Comment: It is inside of the method call animation.calculateTick(tpf) in my code. For lack of space I did not show what is inside that method. Somewhere down that path the method addAnimation was called

Comment: oh ok. this explains a lot. so you now use the concurrent collection as a solution?

Comment: No, after consideration, I actually make a copy of the list when iterating through it. The thing that I do not like about the concurrent collection is that it is a bit undeterministic. Though I tested it and looks like it works also.